# How to recover a partition accidentally formated by Windows Server Backup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. I have two hard disks attached. The second hard disk contained two partitions (E and F). While running the Windows Server Backup I gave the path to backup the primary partition (C) on a schedule to one of the above partitions.

The backup schedule was running successfully until today I manually run the scheduled backup. I was shocked to see the message "Formatting..". Suddenly both the partitions of the other drive were lost. I could see Windows Server Backup merged the two partitions and created a dedicated backup partition.

Is there a way to recover those lost partitions?

Comment: Can you restore them from your backup or did they house all your backups?

Comment: @Robert There were no backups but it contained some old files. Windows Server Backup automatically formatted the two partitions and merged them. It also made it a permanent backup device. That hard drive is now not visible in My Computer altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The partitions were deleted and reformatted. You'll have to restore from backup or use data recovery software. There's no easy "oops" button to click for this one.